# Returning array from c to python ctypes

Tags: python, c, ctypes

So I have the following method in c

```
rx_data_t readBuffer(HANDLE connection)
{
    rx_data_t buffer[512];

    _read_receiver_buffer(connection, &buffer[0]);

    return buffer;
}
```

Results are returned from _read_receiver_buffer fine and I can iterate through buffer no problem.

However I am having trouble returning the results back to Python using the ctypes library.

rx_data_t is a pointer to an array of structures with the following layout:

```
{
    unsigned long receive_time;
    unsigned short low;
    unsigned short high;
} rx_data_t;
```

Comment: That shouldn't even compile. An array is returned as a pointer to the first element, so you're returning an `rx_data_t *` pointer, not an `rx_data_t` struct. Also the `buffer` array is allocated on the stack, so returning a pointer to it is meaningless. You need to `malloc` storage for the array, which in turns means you need to `free` the allocated memory when it's no longer needed.

Comment: Either that, or make `buffer` `static`, in which case the storage persists when you return from the function. However, the function will then not be re-entrant/thread-safe, and if you ever want to use it in a multi-threaded program, you'll have to provide appropriate synchronization...

Comment: Did you solve your problem yet ?

Comment: Sorry i honestly don't remember, ive not been part of that project for a while